# How do I resolve the error Error in print(center$title) : object 'center' not found in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am using shiny in R Studio in order to build a web application for a movie recommendation system. I am trying to get an input of username and age and when the user presses the submit button, the server prosesses some R code and then the output should be a list of movie titles.

The code I have done for the ui is

```
ui <- fluidPage(

    titlePanel("MOVIE RECOMMENDATION SYSTEM"),

    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            print("Enter age: "),
            numericInput("user.age", NULL, "20","13", "70"),
            print("Enter name: "),
            textInput("user.name",NULL , NULL, NULL, placeholder = "Enter Name"),
            submitButton("ENTER")
        ),

        mainPanel(

            print(center$title)

        )
    )
)
```

the server contains the code I want to run in R which I have tested and it works. title is a column in the center data frame which is created in the server code.

But I am getting the error

```
 Error in print(center$title) : object 'center' not found
```

Comment: What is `print(center$title)` supposed to do? I've never seen it in a shiny app

Comment: @bretauv `print(center$title)` is meant to print all the items in the column title. I use it in the regular r code. Is there anything else I can do in place of it?

Comment: You can't center a sidebar. If you want to center all the inputs, use `column()`.

Comment: @bretauv center here refers to the dataset center. `center$title` refers to the column "title" in the dataset "center"

Comment: First, it appears that the dataset is not loaded in your environment because `object 'center' not found `. Second, the `ui` is not the place where you display the dataset, you have to do it in the `server`. Put `tableOutput` in the `ui` and `renderTable` in the `server` and put `center$title` inside the `renderTable`. See [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/written-tutorial/lesson4/) for more details.

Comment: thankyou @bretauv that worked